# PHP echo in Jquery script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem displaying PHP `echo` from jQuery script. The code is displayed but in plain text. I don't want to load it from PHP. I tried to do everything but it had no effect except the one that displays the code as PHP. By adding instead of replace text, HTML only shows quotation marks.

Is there any solution to this?

```js
var currentBackground = 0;
var currentNaglowek = 0;
var currentTekst = 0;

var backgrounds = [];
backgrounds[0] = 'https://via.placeholder.com/1920x360';
backgrounds[1] = 'https://via.placeholder.com/1920x360';
backgrounds[2] = 'https://via.placeholder.com/1920x360';

var naglowek = [];
naglowek[0] = "<?php echo ($language['carousel_header1']); ?>";
naglowek[1] = "<?php echo ($language['carousel_header2']); ?>";
naglowek[2] = "<?php echo ($language['carousel_header3']); ?>";

var tekst = [];
tekst[0] = "<?php echo ($language['carousel_text1']); ?>";
tekst[1] = "<?php echo ($language['carousel_text2']); ?>";
tekst[2] = "<?php echo ($language['carousel_text3']); ?>";

function changeBackground() {
  currentBackground++;
  currentNaglowek++;
  currentTekst++;

  if (currentBackground > 2)
    currentBackground = 0;
  if (currentNaglowek > 2)
    currentNaglowek = 0;
  if (currentTekst > 2)
    currentTekst = 0;

  $('#sliderBox ').fadeOut(1500, function() {
    $('#sliderTexts').html('<p>"' + naglowek[currentNaglowek] + '"</p>');
    $('#sliderTexts').html('<p>"' + tekst[currentTekst] + '"</p>');
    $('#sliderBox ').css({
      'background-image': "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
    });
    $('#sliderBox ').fadeIn(1500);
  });

  setTimeout(changeBackground, 7000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(changeBackground, 7000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sliderBox">
  <div class="sliderContent">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8" id="sliderTexts"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Have you checked the console for errors? What is the actual output from the PHP?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please replace the PHP with text and add images from placeholder.com for example

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the problem that the jquery is not printing echo of php string. There are no errors. Output of all vars is "text"

Comment: remove the quotation marks from <?php ..... ?> so php recognise them as statements and not just strings

Comment: @SaymoinSam — PHP doesn't give `"` (or anything else) *outside* of `<?php ... ?>` any special meaning.

Comment: Just a small note: A better way to encode string values into a `<script>` tag from PHP would be `naglowek[0] = <?php echo json_encode($language['carousel_header1']); ?>;`. This will properly encode quotes that are in the string and prevent javascript errors.

Comment: You still need to do   `$('#sliderTexts').html('<p>' + naglowek[currentNaglowek] + '</p><p>' + tekst[currentTekst] + '</p>');`

Comment: The only way to display that is by loading it through PHP. Why don't you want to load it through PHP?

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute PHP, it needs to be in a file that is registered to be passed through PHP by the webserver. Typically this means giving it a `.php` file extension (and **not** a `.js` file extension).

Since PHP will, by default, claim that anything it outputs is HTML, you also need to override that by being explicit about the content-type:

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
```

You might also want to explicitly generate [caching headers](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) so the JS isn't rerequested with every page load.

---

You might also consider breaking the file apart and sticking to a traditional static JavaScript program which gets its data from a JSON endpoint via `fetch`.